# Why double.Parse() throws FormatException only through rdp?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, double

I have a realy weird error. I have a .Net application, that make an exception while parsing a string to a double.
But this is happening only trough RDP!

I made a simple exe:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     try
     {
          string s = "1.5";
          double d = double.Parse(s);
          Console.WriteLine("RES: " + d);
          Console.Read();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Message: "+e.Message+", trace: "+e.StackTrace);
          Console.Read();
     }
}
```

When I execute on local it works, ut in RDP i have an error [image]

Any idea? the machine is a Windows 2012R2, that is also a domain controller.
I try to execute this little app with the same user, only difference is RDP/Local

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you check the localization on the remote machine. It might be using a different decimal point notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`double.Parse` uses your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings on the *current* environment by default.

Sounds like your remote environment uses a culture that doesn't have `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx), that's why you get `FormatException`.

As an anternative, you can use [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a second parameter in your parsing method which has `.` already as a `NumberDecimalSeparator`.

```
double d = double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can change the culture settings of your remote environment the same culture using in your local environment.