# Having trouble inserting double such as 4.8 (for example) (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm having some issues while inserting a double for example: 4.8. The program does not want to read it.
As you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please add your code as text to your question. You can use [edit] to [edit] your question.

Comment: The error says your input is not understood. Can you show us what you have typed?

Comment: Probably your culture use "," for decimals, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673269/why-double-parse-throws-formatexception-only-through-rdp

Comment: It throws an error even in the most simple codes:

using System;

namespace SoftUni
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double income = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(income);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Found the issue. It came from the regional settings on my Windows. It was set to use "," instead of "." so every time I used ".", the error came.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be your cultural setting. Probably expected comma instead of a point. Try this:

```
double income = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double income;
// In case you need style and culture
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
// Keep on reading until you make it
while(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), style, culture, out income));
```